# Unix, displaying message "no such directory"

Tags: unix

```
#!/bin/sh

LOCATION=$1

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
echo "Usage:./test1 <directory_name>"

else
echo "Number of directories: $(find $LOCATION -type d | wc -l) "
echo "Number of files: $(find $LOCATION -type f | wc -l)"
echo "Number of readable: $(find $LOCATION -type f -readable | wc -l )"
echo "Number of writable: $(find $LOCATION -type f -writable | wc -l )"
echo "Number of executable: $(find $LOCATION -type f -executable | wc -l )"
fi

if [ $Location does not exist? ]
then
echo "This Directory does not exist"
if
```

I am pretty new to unix, i am not sure how to do the last part? if the the directory does not exist, what should i say inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an easy one to implement. Bash included [File Test Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) that provide such functionality.

**Example**:

```
    if [ ! -d $LOCATION ]
    then
        echo "This Directory does not exist"
    fi
```

**EDIT**: Also move that to the top so if the directory does not exist you do not waste time and resources checking a non-existant directory. This will also avoid further warnings.

**Example**:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOCATION=$1

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
echo "Usage:./test1 <directory_name>"
else
   if [ -d $LOCATION ]
   then
        echo "Number of directories: $(find $LOCATION -type d | wc -l) "
        echo "Number of files: $(find $LOCATION -type f | wc -l)"
        echo "Number of readable: $(find $LOCATION -type f -readable | wc -l )"
        echo "Number of writable: $(find $LOCATION -type f -writable | wc -l )"
        echo "Number of executable: $(find $LOCATION -type f -executable | wc -l )"
   else
        echo "This Directory does not exist"
   fi
fi
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Second "if" should be "fi".

Comment: @Jef good catch, shouldn't have copy/pasted OP code without checking.

Comment: Thank you soo much, this works, just to make it clear, the second part of the if statement is saying: if whatever i type in for $Location if is a directory, then it will echo all those, if its not a directory echo this Directory does not exist? is thar right?

Comment: @user3488212 that is exactly right. That way you do not waste runtime running the other commands on a non-existent directory. Please accept answer if you feel it properly answered your question and welcome to SO!